# Sed to replace variable length string between 2 known patterns

Tags: sed

I'd like to be able to replace a string between 2 known patterns. The catch is that I want to replace it by a string of the same length that is composed only of 'x'.

Let's say I have a file containing:

```
Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString
Hello.ShortString.SecondString
```

I'd like the output to be like this:

```
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
```

Comment: You are not explicit about what your "known strings" are. Is it `Hello.` and `.SecondString` or it is just dots? What to do with the line `Foo.bar.Baz`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `sed` loops

You can use `sed`, though the thinking required is not wholly obvious:

```
sed ':a;s/^\(Hello\.x*\)[^x]\(.*\.SecondString\)/\1x\2/;t a'
```

This is for GNU `sed`; BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` and other versions may be fussier and require:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/^\(Hello\.x*\)[^x]\(.*\.SecondString\)/\1x\2/' -e 't a'
```

The logic is identical in both:

- Create a label `a`
- Substitute the lead string and a sequence of `x`'s (capture 1), followed by a non-`x`, and arbitrary other data plus the second string (capture 2), and replace it with the contents of capture 1, an `x` and the content of capture 2.
- If the `s///` command made a change, go back to the label `a`.

It stops substituting when there are no non-`x`'s between the two marker strings.

Two tweaks to the regex allow the code to recognize two copies of the pattern on a single line.  Lose the `^` that anchors the match to the beginning of the line, and change `.*` to `[^.]*` (so that the regex is not quite so greedy):

```
$ echo Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString |
> sed ':a;s/\(Hello\.x*\)[^x]\([^.]*\.SecondString\)/\1x\2/;t a'
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
$
```

#### Using the hold space

[hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) suggests an alternative approach in `sed` using the hold space.  This can be implemented using:

```
$ echo Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString |
> sed 's/^\(Hello\.\)\([^.]\{1,\}\)\(\.SecondString\)/\1@\3@@\2/
>      h
>      s/.*@@//
>      s/./x/g
>      G
>      s/\(x*\)\n\([^@]*\)@\([^@]*\)@@.*/\2\1\3/
>      '
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
$
```

This script is not as robust as the looping version but works OK as written when each line matches the lead-middle-tail pattern.  It first splits the line into three sections: the first marker, the bit to be mangled, and the second marker.  It reorganizes that so that the two markers are separated by `@`, followed by `@@` and the bit to be mangled.  `h` copies the result to the hold space.  Remove everything up to and including the `@@`; replace each character in the bit to be mangled by `x`, then copy the material in the hold space after the `x`'s in the pattern space, with a newline separating them.  Finally, recognize and capture the `x`'s, the lead marker, and the tail marker, ignoring the newline, the `@` and `@@` plus trailing material, and reassemble as lead marker, `x`'s, and tail marker.

To make it robust, you'd recognize the pattern and then group the commands shown inside `{` and `}` to group them so they're only executed when the pattern is recognized:

```
sed '/^\(Hello\.\)\([^.]\{1,\}\)\(\.SecondString\)/{
     s/^\(Hello\.\)\([^.]\{1,\}\)\(\.SecondString\)/\1@\3@@\2/
     h
     s/.*@@//
     s/./x/g
     G
     s/\(x*\)\n\([^@]*\)@\([^@]*\)@@.*/\2\1\3/
     }'
```

Adjust to suit your needs...

#### Adjusting to suit your needs

> [I tried one of your solutions and it worked fine.]
>   However when I try to replace the 'hello' by my real string (which is
>   '`1.2.840.`') and my second string (which is simply a dot '`.`'), things stop
>   working.  I guess all these dots confuse the `sed` command.
>   What I try to achieve is transform this '`1.2.840.10008.`' to
>   '`1.2.840.xxxxx.`'
>
> And this pattern happens several times in my file with variable number
>   of characters to be replaced between the '`1.2.840.`' and the next dot '`.`'

There are times when it is important to get your question close enough to the real scenario — this may be one such.  Dot is a metacharacter in
`sed` regular expressions (and in most other dialects of regular expression — shell globbing being the noticeable exception).  If the 'bit to be mangled' is always digits, then we can tighten up the regular expressions, though actually (when I look at the code ahead) the tightening really isn't imposing much in the way of a restriction.

Pretty much any solution using regular expressions is a balancing act that has to pit convenience and abbreviation against reliability and precision.

**Revised code plus data**

```
cat <<EOF |
transform this '1.2.840.10008.' to '1.2.840.xxxxx.'
OK, and hence 1.2.840.21. and 1.2.840.20992. should lose the 21 and 20992.
EOF

sed ':a;s/\(1\.2\.840\.x*\)[^x.]\([^.]*\.\)/\1x\2/;t a'
```

**Example output:**

```
transform this '1.2.840.xxxxx.' to '1.2.840.xxxxx.'
OK, and hence 1.2.840.xx. and 1.2.840.xxxxx. should lose the 21 and 20992.
```

The changes in the script are:

```
sed ':a;s/\(1\.2\.840\.x*\)[^x.]\([^.]*\.\)/\1x\2/;t a'
```

1. Add `1\.2\.840\.` as the start pattern.
2. Revise the 'character to replace' expression to 'not `x` or `.`'.
3. Use just `\.` as the tail pattern.

You could replace the `[^x.]` with `[0-9]` if you're sure you only want digits matched, in which case you won't have to worry about spaces as discussed below.

You may decide you don't want spaces to be matched so that a casual comment like:

```
The net prefix is 1.2.840. And there are other prefixes too.
```

does not end up as:

```
The net prefix is 1.2.840.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
```

In which case, you probably need to use:

```
sed ':a;s/\(1\.2\.840\.x*\)[^x. ]\([^ .]*\.\)/\1x\2/;t a'
```

And so the changes continue until you've got something precise enough to do what you want without doing anything you don't want on your current data set.  Writing bullet-proof regular expressions requires a precise specification of what you want matched, and can be quite hard.

Comment: Plus one, since you were the first who posted a `sed` solution. It was such a fun to tinker that, so I posted my solution too. They are almost the same..

Comment: Deleted it, yours is perfect ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Your solution was very similar indeed.

Comment: Probably since this is the only way with sed? (I'm not sure, mostly there are many ways to do things in sed. Thinking of a different solution).

Comment: @hek2mgl: I think that a loop is basically the only way to do it in `sed`.  The Perl solution uses a loop with the `"x" x length($1)`; the `awk` solution uses an explicit loop. In `sed`, the partitioning of the string can't use fewer than two remembered segments, I think, but you can semi-reasonably introduce up to three extra (for a total of five): `/^\(Hello\.\)\(x*\)\([^x]\)\(.*\)\(\.SecondString\)/` to capture the leading marker, the already converted `x`'s, the next non-`x`, the unexamined characters, and the trailing marker separately.

Comment: I first thought of putting the whole line into hold space, extract the inner word in pattern buffer and replace all chars by `x` and then *inject it somehow* back into the contents of the hold buffer. I couldn't find a way, then I used the loop.

Comment: @hek2mgl: try the addendum to my answer -- but I think the loop is easier to understand.

Comment: The trick with the newline to separate the hold buffer and the `x`'s is nice!! Many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Hi First of all thank you for your help. I've tryed echo Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString |
> sed ':a;s/\(Hello\.x*\)[^x]\([^.]*\.SecondString\)/\1x\2/;t a'
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString and it did work fine. However when i try to replace the 'hello' by my real string witch is '1.2.840.' and my second string witch is simply a dot '.' things stop to work. I gess all these dots confuse the sed command. what i try to achieve is transform this '1.2.840.10008.' to '1.2.840.xxxxx.'

Comment: And this pattern happens several times in my file with variable number of characters to be replaced between the '1.2.840. ant the dot '.'

Comment: OK i found how to adapt :-) I only had to put my dots in [.] Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I like this. Just a thought about the hold buffer solution: Instead of `@` and `@@`, it is more robust to use newlines as markers because you know newlines don't appear in the input line (it being a single line). If I weren't too late, I'd suggest `sed '/\(Hello\.\)\(.*\)\(\.SecondString\)/ { s//\1\n\2\n\3/; h; s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/; s/./x/g; G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2\1/ }'`. Apart from the newline markers, the only notable difference is the use of `//` to avoid repeating the pattern.

Comment: @Wintermute: interesting and accurate observations — thank you.  If the hold-buffer was the better solution, your refinements would be worthwhile.  However, I don't think it is as good as the other solution, mainly because it is considerably longer and not as clear (though that could be 'in the eye of the beholder').  I assume the hold space solution could be upgraded to handle multiple occurrences of the pattern on a single line, but I've certainly not spent the time testing to make sure it can.

Comment: I think which solution is better depends on the use case. Without having actually benchmarked it, I'd expect the hold buffer solution to be considerably more performant for long matches because the regex has to be tested much less often, and that could sometimes be an important advantage. As for multiple matches on a line -- that could be patched in with a different regex and a loop around the hold buffer bit, but at that point I'd probably switch to Perl in order to get non-greedy matches and do it in one go.

Answer (score 2):

I'd choose perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=Hello\.)(.*?)(?=\.SecondString)/ "x" x length($1) /e' file
```

Comment: I was hoping that awk's `sprintf` can do repetition of chars. Now I'm also thinking `perl` is the best choice..

Comment: With GNU awk, you can capture parts of a regex: `gawk 'match($0,/(.*Hello\.)(.+)(\.SecondString.*)/,m) {gsub(/./,"x",m[2]); $0 = m[1] m[2] m[3]} 1'`

Comment: Looking better than my attempt! :) The `gsub()` you are using is the solution to the repetition of chars. But I deleted my answer because of the absence of the `?` (non-greedy) quantifier in awk. (It's really handy). The regex will simply not work without it. I missed that.

Comment: ... ok, it could work, if it is sure that there will be a dot between the words ...

Comment: @hek2mgl you can use awks `sprintf` to generate sequences of chars of a given length by doing, e.g. in this case: `BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$2=sprintf("%*s",length($2),""); gsub(/ /,"x",$2)} 1`. You need to generate the sequence of blanks first and then replace each blank with the char in question. Of course, in this case you don't need any of that, just isolate the string you want to replace and replace each char in the string with an "x".

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah that works. glenn showed that already. I thought I can specify the character to be used for the padding so that I can save the `gsub()`. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I don't see where Glenn is using `sprintf()` to generate a string of chars of a given length which is what you had asked about but maybe he deleted it. The only other char you can use for the padding is zero. I've often wished you could specify an arbitrary char but sadly no...

Comment: @EdMorton, that's what the perl `x` operator is doing. It's left-hand operand is the string to repeat, and the right-hand operand is the number of repetitions: `"x" x length($1)`

Comment: Glenn @hek2mgl had said `I was hoping that awk's sprintf can do repetition of chars` so I was just responding to that with an example of how to do it. So the letter `x` is an operator in perl, huh? How would you write the equivalent of awks `"x" x 3` where `x` is a variable and that means string concatenation? If I wrote `"x" y 3` in perl where `y` is a variable would it produce a syntax error? Can I create/use a variable named `x`?

Comment: I don't know enough perl to try anything else but I just tried `x x length($1)` and it produced the same output as `"x" x length($1)` but `"y" x length($1)` produced a string of ys while  `y x length($1)` produced `Transliteration pattern not terminated at -e line 1.`. What a language. Don't do drugs kids....

Comment: `y` is a perl command, stolen from sed, hende the unterminated translit. message. awk's `"x" x 3` string concatenation in perl requires the string concatenation operator: `"x" . $x . 3`

Comment: @EdMorton Oh, the party is over already, :) You said `I've often wished you could specify an arbitrary char but sadly no.` Yeah, I wished that too, and for whatever reason I thought it is possible with `awk`.

Comment: Glenn - ah, I see, I had no idea that `y` was also a command, thanks for explaining. `w` behaves like `"w"`. I guess the creators of perl REALLY wanted to provide brevity at all costs! I can't criticize their need for a concatenation operator though, awk would be clearer if it also required that.

Comment: Yeah, every language has its warts. perl is particularly toad-like. It took me a long time to get over python's enforced whitespace. bash is just ridiculous. But that's the world we live in.

Comment: I read an article recently which addressed the common claim that "only perl can understand perl" (ie. the interpreter knows what a script means but people don't) and that article pointed out that that's not true because not even perl can understand perl. There's several articles confirming that claim, google "perl cannot be parsed" if interested. Not saying I follow the whole debate but I did find it interesting...

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F. '{for (i=1;i<=length($2);i++) a=a"x";$2=a;a=""}1' OFS="." file
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash Works Too

While the `perl`, `sed` and `awk` solutions are probably the better choice, a Bash solution is not that difficult (just longer). Bash has good character-by-character handling abilities as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

rep=0    # replace flag
skip=0   # delay reset flag

while read -r line; do                 # read each line

    for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++)); do   # for each character in the line

        # if '.' and replace on, turn off and set skip
        [ ${line:i:1} == '.' -a $rep -eq 1 ] && { rep=0; skip=1; }

        # print char or "x" depending on replace flag
        [ $rep -eq 0 ] && printf "%c" ${line:i:1} || printf "x"

        # if '.' and replace off
        if [ ${line:i:1} == '.' -a $rep -eq 0 ]; then
            # if skip, turn skip off, else set replace on
            [ $skip -eq 1 ] && skip=0 || rep=1
        fi

    done

    printf "\n"

done

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/replacefile.txt
Hello.StringToBeReplaced.SecondString
Hello.ShortString.SecondString
```

**Output**

```
$ bash replacedot.sh < dat/replacefile.txt
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of your sanity, just use awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {gsub(/./,"x",$2)} 1' file
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
Hello.xxxxxxxxxxx.SecondString
```

Comment: `For the sake of your sanity` hihi :) I assume for most people on planet even `awk` isn't good for sanity ... :)

Comment: Given that by definition half the people you meet are of below average intelligence, I suppose that also means that half the people you meet are below some average threshold of sanity? It would explain so much.... :-).